# Evaluating dynamic information for constructing objects in .NET

Tags: xml, linq, reflection, linq-to-objects, dynamic-linq

I am having a problem of generating expressions of all kinds which at the end will be evaluated and on the basis of results of those expressions or their direct results will be apply to destination column/property while creation of that type.

For example :

Product

While creating Package object ( left hand side of equal op is destination col )

```
PackageId = dbContext.Products.SingleOrDefault(pr=>pr.Code== "name" ).ProductId

PackageName = dbContext.Packages.SingleOrDefault( pr=>pr.Name == model.Name ) != null && 
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CodeName) ?
dbContext.Packages.SingleOrDefault( pr=>pr.Name == model.Name ).PackageId : null

and so on.....almost 100 fields I need to initialize in this way, where expressions.
```

This whole comparable data on which expressions are supposed to be formed already cached in memory. ( i.e No database round trips would take place, whole static lookup data is already available in memory )

Now the problem is : all these decisions are being made on the GUI ( i.e mapping of the source column to destination column, mapping on the basis of certain expression evaluation, or mapping a result of an expression to destination column ). Hence I am preparing an XML for including this whole info at field level in such a way..

```
<Mapping>
<Field TargetField="CountryGroup" >
    <Rule>
        <Compare pram1="Versandart" param2="24" >
            <True Result="2"/>
            <False Result="1"/>
        </Compare>
    </Rule>
</Field>    
<Field TargetField="UnLoadingCountryId" >
    <Rule>
        <Compare param1="Versendart" param="24">
            <True ResultType  ="CallToDB" TableName="Country" SourceCol="Iso" TargetCol="ELKZ" TargetValueColumn="CountryId"/>
            <False ResultType ="ScalerValue" value="94"/> 
        </Compare>  <!-- targetting expression was :  bell.Versandart == "24" ? Countries.SingleOrDefault(pr => pr.Iso == bell.ELKZ.Left(2))?.CountryId : 94,-->
    </Rule>
</Field>
<Field TargetField="CostCenter" >
    <Rule>
        <IsNullOrEmpty param1="Kundengruppe">
            <True ResultType  ="ScalerValue" value="S"/>
            <False ResultType ="SelfAssignment" value="Kundengruppe"/>
        </Compare>
    </Rule>
</Field>

<Field TargetField="TODId" >
    <Rule>
        <IsNullOrEmpty param1="Versandstelle" param2="1031">
            <True ResultType ="CallToDB" TableName="Tod" search="Border" TargetValueColumn="TodId"/>
            <True ResultType ="CallToDB" TableName="Tod" search="Delivered" TargetValueColumn="TodId"/>

            <!-- targetting expression was : Versandstelle == "1031" ? 1028 : 1027 -->
        </Compare>
    </Rule>
</Field>
```

I don't know at this moment, how good this xml structure would be and how this would all the way store each and every information which would dynamically be read and applied. Further this xml might get complicated more and more because of nested expressions or because of multiple kinds of operations on the basis of results of expressions.

For this , I am considering following options:

1. **Creating dynamic expressions using DLINQ ( later on calling compile )**
2. **Having seperate class for each and every operation ( i.e Compare, Add, Substract, Searching into the database ( getting DbSets
   dynamically and searching for perticular property using reflection)**

First option is more easily construct able than later one. Because creating dynamic expressions could be much easy. But that would be much slower because of dynamic nature.

Second option where we should have separate commands( classes ) for doing respective operations might be faster but it would create much complexity in the application. Because, each operation is dynamically invoked on the basis of Xml Tags.

Can I have better recommendations on this? What should be follow?
Xml structure needs to be refine?

Comment: I think you should do some more research on Lexigraphical languages.  I would start with the old Unix YACC (Yet Another Compiler Compiler) and the Unix method Lex.  See : http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/

Comment: I am sure that people have already created several ways of evaluating expressions in .NET. I am not concerned about evaluation. I am concerned about the best approach in terms of speed and maintainability.

Comment: That is why I recommended YACC.  YACC was developed by Programming Scientists and Bell Lab in the early 1970s when computers ran a lost slower than today and speed of the algorithm was important.

Comment: I am looking for something other than compiler language building or formation of language stuff. I am sure, something can be achieved while remaining in .NET

Comment: I'm not saying to use YACC.  Just saying to use Data Definitions similar to YACC.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more what do you mean by using data definitions? I am sorry, I didn't get the idea.

Comment: Appendix A, B , and C of YACC give examples of how to define a language.  Your rules are very similar to YACC rules of defining a language.